# iOS How to handle time it takes for DB to update

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, multithreading, sqlite

Everytime my app start I have it check if there has been any changes in our server database since the last time the app started.  If there is the server sends back a json string that I must parse and enter into my sqlite database in the app.

I do this from the AppDelegate, but my problem is that if there is a lot of data to update then the AppDelegate pushes the next ViewController before the update to the database is done.  I would like to not allow the app to move onto the first ViewController until the database update is complete.

How would I go about doing this?
Or is there a better way to handle this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't display "nothing" till you check the database. Instead display a view that shows a message such as: "Checking for updates...". If possible show a progress bar as well.

Comment: I was just thinking something like that.  What I'm trying right now is the have a custom splash screen over the first ViewController until the database updating is complete.  I'm having trouble getting a view to lay over the Navigationbar and tabbar i have in the first ViewController.  I've tried hiding both of them, but the tabbar won't disappear.

Comment: Something like this might make the progress HUD easier to create. https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD

Comment: yep, i use MBProgressHUD. this shows a HUD that is of similar design as apple uses (like the HUD displayed when you change the volume).  you can show while excuting your DB update and then launch the 2nd view controller when complete.

Comment: That is perfect.  One last question.  What would be the best way to find out when the update is finished?